# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write' - Print application answers into Excel

Tags: python, excel, pycharm, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to print output data from a python app into an excel file. I was able to create the associated columns with the below code by writing the relevant names into A1, B2 etc. How do I get these outputs to enter the rows below but only if there is no other information there?

```
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(
            'C:\\Users\\W\\Project\\Interface\\Portal Information Store.xlsx')
        worksheet = ("Portal Data")

        worksheet.write('A2', self.txt_fname.get(), self.txt_lname.get())
        worksheet.write('B2', self.txt_contact.get())
        worksheet.write('C2', self.txt_email.get())
        worksheet.write('D2', self.txt_pass.get())
        worksheet.write('E2', self.txt_confpass.get())
        worksheet.write('F2', self.txt_dob.get())
        worksheet.write('G2', self.txt_newloc.get())
        workbook.close()
```

I keep getting the error code:

```
  File "C:\Users\W\Project\Interface\Portal.py", line 109, in register_data
    worksheet.write('A2', self.txt_fname.get(), self.txt_lname.get())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you want `worksheet = workbook.get_worksheet_by_name("Portal Data")`

Comment: Tried this and the error code changed.

`
  File "C:\Users\W\Project\Interface\Portal.py", line 109, in register_data
    worksheet.write('A2', self.txt_fname.get(), self.txt_lname.get())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
`

Comment: Then there is no worksheet named "Portal Data" in that workbook.

Comment: Are you trying to write to a new or existing Excel file?

Comment: @jmcnamara existing file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used this library before, however, I know of a similar lib - openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='C:\\Users\\W\\Project\\Interface\\Portal Information Store.xlsx')
```

You can continue assigning values as follows:

```
wb["A2"]=self.txt_fname.get() + self.txt_lname.get()
wb["B2"]=self.txt_contact.get()
```

To check if the cell is empty or not do the following:

```
if wb["A2"].value=="":
       wb["A2"]=self.txt_fname.get() + self.txt_lname.get() // or whatever action needed
```

Comment: i tried:  
`wb = load_workbook(filename='C:\\Users\\W\\Project\\Interface\\Portal Information 
Store.xlsx')  
wb["A2"] = self.txt_fname.get() + self.txt_lname.get()  
if wb["A2"].value == "":  
    wb["A2"] = self.txt_fname.get() + self.txt_lname.get()  
else:  
    wb[cell below] = self.txt_fname.get() + self.txt_lname.get()`  
and now i get:   `File "C:\Users\W\Project\Interface\Portal.py", line 96, in register_data
   wb["A2"] = self.txt_fname.get() + self.txt_lname.get()  
AttributeError: __setitem__`  
i realise that "cell below" will not work but i am unsure of how to do this

Comment: Seems like that's an error in the Flask / Django app that you're using